# Is there a way to provide a dropdown for the integrated shell to use in VS Code

Tags: bash, shell, visual-studio-code

This might be the wrong place to ask this question, but I'm not sure where I would ask it, so here goes!

I am currently between using 2 shells, cmd and Bash on Windows, and I mainly use VS Code for most of my programming needs.  I know that there is a way to select a default terminal path, using `"terminal.integrated.shell.windows": C:\\insert\path\here"`, but since I am using both shells, would it be possible to select (every single time I opened up a new terminal window) which shell to use?

I couldn't really find this anywhere, but I just thought it'd be really convenient if it did exist. Thanks for the help!